# JavaScript form validation fails after first check

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

The first function works in terms of the alert box, but it doesn't clear the invalid input. The other functions are written exactly the same, but the browser doesn't react to them.

Note they all have unique id.

```js
function casing_val() {
  let x = document.getElementById("casing_diam_mm").value;
  let y = document.getElementById("hole_diam_mm").value;
  if (x > y) {
    x.value = "";
    alert("casing diameter must be less than hole diameter. Try again.");
  }
}

function firstscreen_val() {
  let st1 = document.getElementById("screen1_top_dbg").value;
  let sb1 = document.getElementById("screen1_bot_dbg").value;

  let z = document.getElementById("depth_dbg").value;
  if (sb1 < st1) {
    alert("Bottom of screen must be lower than the top. Try again.");
  }
  if (st1 > z) {
    alert("Top of screen must be above the total depth. Try again.");
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="hole_diam_mm" class="sr-only">Hole diameter (mm)</label>
<input type="text" name="hole_diam_mm" id="hole_diam_mm" tabindex="4" class="form-control" placeholder="Hole diameter (mm)" value="<?php echo $hole_diam_mm?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="casing_diam_mm" class="sr-only">Casing diameter (mm)</label>
  <input onchange=casing_val() type="text" name="casing_diam_mm" id="casing_diam_mm" tabindex="4" class="form-control" placeholder="Casing diameter (mm)" value="<?php echo $casing_diam_mm ?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="screen1_top_dbg" class="sr-only">Top of first screen</label>
  <input type="text" name="screen1_top_dbg" id="screen1_top_dbg" tabindex="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Top of first screen" value="<?php echo $screen1_top_dbg ?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="screen1_bot_dbg" class="sr-only">Bottom of first screen</label>
  <input type="text" name="screen1_bot_dbg" id="screen1_bot_dbg" tabindex="6" class="form-control" placeholder="Bottom of first screen" value="<?php echo $screen1_bot_dbg ?>">
</div>
```

Comment: Only one of your inputs has an `onchange` attribute. And you're calling `x.value = "";` except that `x` is a string, it's the value, not the element itself. Look at what you're initially setting `x` to.

Comment: Convert string to an integer or float and then use if statement. You can do it with parseFloat()  or parseInt() method.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the text input is not being cleared is because you are setting x to the value of the element and not the element itself. Also, you should use parseFloat() to convert the string values to numeric values before checking if one is greater than the other

You can fix this with out changing your code too much by storing the element in a variable and then use that variable to set the value.

```
function casing_val() {
  // Set the element variables
  let xElement = document.getElementById("casing_diam_mm");
  let yElement = document.getElementById("hole_diam_mm");
  
  let x = parseFloat(xElement.value); // parseFloat converts string to floating number
  let y =  parseFloat(yElement.value);

  if (x > y) {
    xElement.value = ""; // use the element variable to set the value
    alert("casing diameter must be less than hole diameter. Try again.");
  }
}
```

The code you provided is incomplete, but I suspect why the other functions might not be firing may be because your inputs might not have onchange event attachted to them.